# Android layouts: Make a <space> expandable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have a Linear Layout (lets say vertical) with 3 vews inside it - A,B and C. Every one of them has a weight (weight-sum is 4).

```
A - layout_weight 1, A is a <space>
B - layout_weight 2, B has real content
C - layout_weight 1, C is a <space>
```

All is good, unless we have to switch to a really low resolution - like 320x240 or 320x480. 
Proportions remain the same, however if I have something important in B (some text for example, or edit fields), it gets clipped and is not shown.

So basically, I'd B's height to be max (wrap content, the layout_weight calculated height)
Also, I'd like C to be min(layout_weight calculated height, height remaining after B was layouted).

I can do this in java code. Is there a layout mechanism in Android xml to achieve such an effect? (As far as I remember I've seen something similiar in html/css).

Comment: probably you could try to use 'min_width' or 'min_height' attribute to set minimum size of your content layout but i'm not sure how it would looks like on small screens

Answer (score 1):

Check the android developer's page about `Providing Resources`. I think the section `Providing Alternative Resources` is what you need to read. In few words - you can provide different resources for different screen sizes (other criteria can be applied too) by giving your `layout` folders different names, like `layout-small`.